# Mongoose returning all fields regarding schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm having a collection in my database called **businesses**. What I want to do is query the database and specific fields, defined in my schema, and not all the fields of the document. I thought that's the reason why the schema exists in the first place ?

**Schema**

```
var businessSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    custom_id: String,
    name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Business', businessSchema);
```

**Express**

```
router.get('/query', function (req, res, next) {
    res.type('json');
    Business.find({custom_id: req.query.custom_id})
        .then(function (data) {
            res.send({data: data});
        }).catch(function (err) {
        return next(new Error(err.message || err));
    })
});
```

**Response**

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "_id":"5a50ac105a0d8452b0e341e5",
         "custom_id":"1",
         "name":"Dave and Jane",
         "status":"active",
         "verified":true,
         "created":1492727550760,
         "email":{
            "address":"dave_jane@whatever.com"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

In the schema I have only custom_id and name, but whatever fields I define (or I don't), all the fields of the documents are returned when `Business.find` executes.

Same behavior as if the schema was empty, thus, returning all fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the select function just set the fields you want as 1 and the ones you don't want as 0. See below:

```
router.get('/query', function (req, res, next) {
    res.type('json');
    Business.find({custom_id: req.query.custom_id}).select({ "name": 1, "_id": 0})
        .then(function (data) {
            res.send({data: data});
        }).catch(function (err) {
        return next(new Error(err.message || err));
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use just **"string"** to tell which fields to fetch and which to exclude

```
Business.find().select("name status")
```

this tells mongoose to **only** fetch field "name", "status" but leave all other field

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing at the end is making a static method for the mongoose model, called `findBusinesses` Instead of calling the regular `find` inside my routes I'm calling the static method, which calls itself find, maps the results and returns.

Here's the code

```
businessSchema.statics.findBusinesses = function (query) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    this.find(query, function (error, data) {
        if (error) return deferred.reject(new Error(error));
        var models = [];
        data.forEach(function(e){
            var b = {
                custom_id: e.custom,
                name: e.name,
                phone: e.phone,
                };
            if(e.email) b.email = e.email.address;
            models.push(b);
        });
        return deferred.resolve(models);     // got it
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`select`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select) to specify the fields that you want the query to return.

**From Doc**

> Specifies which document fields to include or exclude (also known as the query "projection")

```
router.get('/query', function (req, res, next) {
    res.type('json');
    Business.find({custom_id: req.query.custom_id}).select({
      name: 1,
      profile_url: 1
    }).then(function (data) {
            res.send({data: data});
        }).catch(function (err) {
        return next(new Error(err.message || err));
    })
});
```

`1` means the field will be included. `0` means excluded. But don't mix both.